# How to control the flow of methods that don't return promise in protractor test

Tags: protractor

I've got a spec where I'm grabbing a screenshot that also requires a dynamic path be created. `makeDir` does not return a promise, so it fires  at the same time (after) `saveScreenshot`. What's the best way to ensure `makeDir` is called first?

```
getPath().then(function(path) {
    makeDir(baseUrl + '/' + path); 
    saveScreenshot(baseUrl + '/' + path + '/' + filename);
})
```

Comment: Where is "makeDir" from?  If it doesn't provide a way to wait for its result via a promise or callback, then there isn't much Protractor can do.  Can you use fs.mkdirSync?  (see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode)

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the answer... makeDir is just a wrapper for mkrirp with some logging. I was hoping to keep it asynchronous but in this case it probably doesn't matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just chain another then() and do the second operation in there.

```
getPath().then(function(path) {
    makeDir(baseUrl + '/' + path); 
    var screenshotpath = baseUrl + '/' + path + '/' + filename;
    return screenshotpath;
}).then(function(screenshotpath) {
    saveScreenshot(screenshotpath);
});
```

Comment: There it is... I was trying to make it too complex. Thanks a bunch!